# Controls missing in UWP application

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

(I am new to UWP environment)

There are missing controls under the toolbox menu in VS 2022: I cannot find labels, tab controls and many other items I would use.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

UWP does not support controls from WinForms WPF and other

Instead of a label, you could use a TextBlock.

This is the new UWP tabcontrol you could use:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/controls/tab-view

You can also check out the WinUi 2 Gallery. Every UWP control is listed there: https://apps.microsoft.com/store/detail/winui-2-gallery/9MSVH128X2ZT

Answer (score 0):

As @FrozenAssassine mentioned, UWP development is different from the traditional desktop app development. The controls are not the same as those you used to use before. The link he provides is really useful.

In addition to his answer, as you are new to UWP development, you could also go through this document: [Develop UWP apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/develop/). This document could help you start the UWP development.